# Is there any way to get shadow from plane without a gap in Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

When I try to get shadow from a plane, I always get some gap between the plane and the shadow. If I disable contact shadows the gap is full:
[image]

When I enable contact shadow it seems like I can get rid of this gap, but no. In some view angles I still see the gap.
[image]

And even if I set contact shadows values too high, I cannot fully get rid of the gap but also I get many unnecessary artifacts.
[image]
This does not happen in Cycles.

So what should I do to get perfect shadow from plane without any gap and artifacts in Eevee?

Comment: Looks like this issue at first glance: https://developer.blender.org/T60205

Answer (score 1):

Adjust Bias and thickness to your needs.
If it's still renders gaps try higher res shadows.
An Example:
[image]

Comment: I tried this. Unfortunately, any setting leaves some gap. You can see it if an angle of view is very close to plane edge. So the only some thikness can help get rid of gap, but I need exactly a plane without any thikness for my purpose.